# Javascript simulate click without moving viewport

Tags: javascript

I've created a sticky add to cart area on shopify. When clicking in the variations it also clicks the variations on the product page as well so it's coherent when the user scrolls up. I've used the click method to do that, but it moves the viewport on the top of the page to show the button that is actually clicked. Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Thanks

Javascript on product page

```
document.querySelectorAll(".product-form__input.sticky label[class='tooltip']").forEach((input) => {
    input.addEventListener('click', function(e){
       document.querySelector("label[for='"+e.target.getAttribute("data-target-option")+"']").click();
    });
    });
```

variants.js

```
   class VariantSelects extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.addEventListener('change', this.onVariantChange);
  }

  onVariantChange() {
    this.updateOptions();
    this.updateMasterId();
    this.toggleAddButton(true, '', false);
    this.updatePickupAvailability();
    if (!this.currentVariant) {
      this.toggleAddButton(true, '', true);
      this.setUnavailable();
    } else {
      this.updateMedia();
      this.updateURL();
      this.updateVariantInput();
      this.renderProductInfo();

    }
  }

  updateOptions() {
    this.options = Array.from(this.querySelectorAll('select'), (select) => select.value);
  }

  updateMasterId() {
    this.currentVariant = this.getVariantData().find((variant) => {
      return !variant.options.map((option, index) => {
        return this.options[index] === option;
      }).includes(false);
    });
  }

  updateMedia() {
    if (!this.currentVariant || !this.currentVariant?.featured_media) return;
    const newMedia = document.querySelector(
      `[data-media-id="${this.dataset.section}-${this.currentVariant.featured_media.id}"]`
    );
    if (!newMedia) return;
    const parent = newMedia.parentElement;
    parent.prepend(newMedia);
    $('.slider-for').slick('slickGoTo', newMedia.offsetParent.attributes[1].nodeValue);
    window.setTimeout(() => { parent.scroll(0, 0) });
  }

  updateURL() {
    if (!this.currentVariant) return;
    window.history.replaceState({ }, '', `${this.dataset.url}?variant=${this.currentVariant.id}`);
  }

  updateVariantInput() {
    const productForms = document.querySelectorAll(`#product-form-${this.dataset.section}, #product-form-installment`);
    productForms.forEach((productForm) => {
      const input = productForm.querySelector('input[name="id"]');
      input.value = this.currentVariant.id;
      input.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }));
    });
  }

  updatePickupAvailability() {
    const pickUpAvailability = document.querySelector('pickup-availability');
    if (!pickUpAvailability) return;

    if (this.currentVariant?.available) {
      pickUpAvailability.fetchAvailability(this.currentVariant.id);
    } else {
      pickUpAvailability.removeAttribute('available');
      pickUpAvailability.innerHTML = '';
    }
  }

  renderProductInfo() {
    fetch(`${this.dataset.url}?variant=${this.currentVariant.id}&section_id=${this.dataset.section}`)
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((responseText) => {
        const id = `price-${this.dataset.section}`;
        const html = new DOMParser().parseFromString(responseText, 'text/html')
        const destination = document.getElementById(id);
        const source = html.getElementById(id);

        if (source && destination) destination.innerHTML = source.innerHTML;

        document.getElementById(`price-${this.dataset.section}`)?.classList.remove('visibility-hidden');
        this.toggleAddButton(!this.currentVariant.available, window.variantStrings.soldOut);

      });
  }

  toggleAddButton(disable = true, text, modifyClass = true) {
    const addButton = document.getElementById(`product-form-${this.dataset.section}`)?.querySelector('[name="add"]');

    if (!addButton) return;

    if (disable) {
      addButton.setAttribute('disabled', true);
      if (text) addButton.textContent = text;
    } else {
      addButton.removeAttribute('disabled');
      addButton.textContent = window.variantStrings.addToCart;
    }

    if (!modifyClass) return;
  }

  setUnavailable() {
    const addButton = document.getElementById(`product-form-${this.dataset.section}`)?.querySelector('[name="add"]');
    if (!addButton) return;
    addButton.textContent = window.variantStrings.unavailable;
    document.getElementById(`price-${this.dataset.section}`)?.classList.add('visibility-hidden');
  }

  getVariantData() {
    this.variantData = this.variantData || JSON.parse(this.querySelector('[type="application/json"]').textContent);
    return this.variantData;
  }
}

customElements.define('variant-selects', VariantSelects);

class VariantRadios extends VariantSelects {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  updateOptions() {
    const fieldsets = Array.from(this.querySelectorAll('fieldset'));
    this.options = fieldsets.map((fieldset) => {
      return Array.from(fieldset.querySelectorAll('input')).find((radio) => radio.checked).value;
    });
  }
}

customElements.define('variant-radios', VariantRadios);
```

Comment: IIRC the `HTMLElement.click()` method does not scroll to the clicked element. Are you sure there is no other listener that scrolls ? What browser are you using, and can you include a minimal reproducible example ?

Comment: @Seblor I too wasn't sure if that was the default behavior of the click method. I've posted some code extracts on my post. Unfortunately I can't post the page as it's password protect company site.

Comment: Why not executing directly the process which would be triggered by the artificial/fake `click` event?

Comment: @PeterSeliger shopify handles a lot behind the scenes when clicking the button, like  changing product image, checking availability etc. Want to prevent writing it again my self.

Answer (score 1):

One should have a look into the documentation of ...

- [`Event` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event#syntax),
- [`UIEvent` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/UIEvent#syntax),
- and into [`EventTarget.dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent).

Maybe something similar to the following example does solve the OP's problem ...

```
document
  .querySelectorAll('.product-form__input.sticky label[class="tooltip"]')
  .forEach(input => {
    input
      .addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
        document
          .querySelector('label[for="' + target.dataset.targetOption + '"]')
          ?.dispatchEvent(
            new UIEvent('click', { "bubbles": true })
          );
      });
    });
```

Comment: Doesn't register the click using dispatchEvent. I think for  this to work there should be a registered event handler on the label, which it seems like Shopify hasn't added.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to work around this using the scroll method of the window element.

```
  document.querySelectorAll(".product-form__input.sticky label[class='tooltip']").forEach((input) => {
    input.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        let currentY = window.scrollY;
        document.querySelector("label[for='"+e.target.getAttribute("data-target-option")+"']").click();
      window.scroll(0,currentY);
    });
    });
```